# How to change the name of the rows of a dataframe?

Tags: dataframe, row

I have a dataframe something like this:

[image]

But I don't want the dates to appear there. I prefer the usual names like 1,2,....56.

How can I solve this?

Help please

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python and pandas, you can try:

```
df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: I'am using R, I forgot mention it